# Etymology of "traje"

Tags: etimología

This word comes from the Latin word *trahō*, which means *to draw, plunder, drag, or trail*. This is where we get **traje**, the Spanish word for *suit*, from. How did such an unrelated word, a verb no less, wind up being the word for an article of clothing in Spanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This reference](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?traje) explains that the idea of a suit is *to draw* attention. It also says that, even if ones of the meaning is "to drag" the idea is closer to "to bring" like in "I brought this dress to be properly dressed for the event".

Take into account that `traje` no only describes the man suit (with jacket and trousers made form the same material) but also a way or code of dressing (uniform).

Comment: Wow! Do you ever sleep? Thanks for the quick answer! :)

Comment: It is easier to recognize the relation by considering the Spanish verb "atraer" (to attract). The origin is set to "_atraer la mirada_", and recognized in other words like "mujer _atractiva_", "ella causa _atracción_", "_ella me a**traj**o_".